# Xamarin iOS - Creating a binding - do I need a different one for classic, unified, AND forms?

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin-studio, ios-library

I've noticed breaking differences if we create a library for the newer, unified API that it won't work in the classic API. Will we also need to create a special one for a forms project? If not is it best to use a binding for classic or unified in a forms project? 
Furthermore is there a way to create a binding that will work in both classic and unified?
So far my attempts have not worked out because of the API changes.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two types of projects in Xamarin.iOS: Classic and Unified.

A Forms project can be either, it's not a third option (it's just a normal Classic or Unified project with a reference to the Forms nuget).

It is not possible to create a single binding assembly that work for both Classic and Unified (for instance one reason is that the Classic version references monotouch.dll, while the Unified version references Xamarin.iOS.dll).

Comment: Thank you. Much what I assumed and very happy to have clarification on it.